# How to display all significant figures on labels when constructing bar charts using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have constructed a bar chart using `ggplot2` and I am displaying the values being graphed on each bar. My problem is that I cannot display the zeros that are trailing the values on each bar.

Here is my dataset:

```
data <- data.frame(product=c('product1',
                              'product2',
                              'product3',
                              'product4',
                              'product5',
                              'product6',
                              'product7',
                              'product8'),
                   test=c(0.60,
                          0.80,
                          0.50,
                          0.70,
                          0.40,
                          0.30,
                          0.20,
                          0.10))
```

The graph is generated with the following code:

```
ggplot(data, aes(product,test))+
  geom_col()+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", col = "grey", fill="black")+
  coord_flip()+
  labs(title="Product comparisons")+
  theme(text=element_text(size=20))+
  theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=12))+
  ylim(NA, 0.90)+
  geom_text(aes(label=round(test, digits=2)), nudge_y= -0.05, color="white", size = 6)
```

Result:
[image]

Only the first decimal is displayed, but I need to display the zeroes after each of the labels. I tried to do this using the `label=round(test, digits=2)` command, but that did not fix it. What can be done to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it!

```
ggplot(data, aes(product,test))+
  geom_col()+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", col = "grey", fill="black")+
  coord_flip()+
  labs(title="Product comparisons")+
  theme(text=element_text(size=20))+
  theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=12))+
  ylim(NA, 0.90)+
  geom_text(aes(label=format(round(test, digits = 2), nsmall = 2)), nudge_y= -0.06, color="white", size =3)
```

Comment: That is what I needed! Thanks for the help.